# C++ Visual Studio 2012 Linker Errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, linker, sfml

I'm pretty new to C++ and I was setting up a project with SFML, which was working fine, I have no code issues according to Visual Studio, but when I debug I get these error messages:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::String::String(char
>   const *,class std::locale const &)"
>   (_*imp*??0String@sf@@QAE@PBDABVlocale@std@@@Z) referenced in function
>   "public: static void __cdecl Game::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Game@@SAXXZ)  c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall sf::String::~String(void)"
>   (*_imp_??1String@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: static
>   void __cdecl Game::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Game@@SAXXZ)  c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall
>   sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)"
>   (*_imp_??0VideoMode@sf@@QAE@III@Z) referenced in function "public:
>   static void __cdecl Game::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Game@@SAXXZ)  c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj 
>   PongSFML
>
> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall
>   sf::Window::create(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const
>   &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)"
>   (*_imp_?create@Window@sf@@QAEXVVideoMode@2@ABVString@2@IABUContextSettings@2@@Z)
>   referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Game::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Game@@SAXXZ)  c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall
>   sf::Window::close(void)" (*_imp_?close@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ) referenced
>   in function "public: static void __cdecl Game::Start(void)"
>   (?Start@Game@@SAXXZ)  c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: bool _*thiscall
>   sf::Window::pollEvent(class sf::Event &)"
>   (*_imp_?pollEvent@Window@sf@@QAE_NAAVEvent@2@@Z) referenced in
>   function "private: static void __cdecl Game::GameLoop(void)"
>   (?GameLoop@Game@@CAXXZ)   c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall
>   sf::Window::display(void)" (*_imp_?display@Window@sf@@QAEXXZ)
>   referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl
>   Game::GameLoop(void)"
>   (?GameLoop@Game@@CAXXZ)   c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall sf::Color::Color(unsigned
>   char,unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char)"
>   (*_imp_??0Color@sf@@QAE@EEEE@Z) referenced in function "private:
>   static void __cdecl Game::GameLoop(void)"
>   (?GameLoop@Game@@CAXXZ)   c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: void _*thiscall
>   sf::RenderTarget::clear(class sf::Color const &)"
>   (*_imp_?clear@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in
>   function "private: static void __cdecl Game::GameLoop(void)"
>   (?GameLoop@Game@@CAXXZ)   c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall
>   sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(void)"
>   (*_imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'private: static class sf::RenderWindow Game::*mainWindow''(void)"
>   (??*_E?_mainWindow@Game@@0VRenderWindow@sf@@A@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual _*thiscall
>   sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)"
>   (*_imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void
>   __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'private: static class sf::RenderWindow Game::*mainWindow''(void)"
>   (??*_F?_mainWindow@Game@@0VRenderWindow@sf@@A@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\PongSFML\Game.obj PongSFML
>
> Error 12  error LNK1120: 11 unresolved
>   externals c:\Users\Harley\cppprojects\Pong\PongSFML\Debug\PongSFML.exe    1   1   PongSFML

I've already done quite a bit of research to try to fix this, but no suggestions worked or changed anything at all. I checked through my additional dependencies and I didn't make any spelling errors:

sfml-main-d.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib;sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-graphics-d.lib;

My release dependencies:

sfml-system.lib;sfml-window.lib;sfml-graphics.lib;sfml-audio.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;

Once again, I'm new to C++ so I may be doing something incredibly stupid. I don't think my source code has anything to do with it, however someone suggested that I add

```
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-main-d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-system-d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-window-d.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "sfml-graphics-d.lib")
```

above my main method, so I did.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, but can you set the linker to `/VERBOSE` so you can see what libraries the linker has found and whether the `.lib`'s you specified are actually getting linked in?

The setting is under C++ > Linker > Progress I think

EDIT: http://s30.postimg.org/485cmfnk1/temp.png <-- Here

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Do you mean C++ in the properties? I checked the C++ area in properties and there was nothing about linker.

Comment: Set the "Show Progress" field to /VERBOSE